# Haskell function argument type inference with typeclasses

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, typeclass

I'm trying to understand haskell error messages, as they are confusing for novice programmer. The simplest example I could find is this:

```
Prelude> 1 + True
<interactive>:2:3:
No instance for (Num Bool)
  arising from a use of `+'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Bool)
In the expression: 1 + True
In an equation for `it': it = 1 + True
```

Why does compiler look for *(Num Bool)* regardless of parameter order? Why does it work after I define the following?

```
instance Num Bool where (+) a b = True;
[...]
Prelude> 1 + True
True
```

How can I make sure *(+)* can be applied to *(Num Bool)* only when second argument is also *(Num Bool)*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error message because both `1` and `+` are polymorphic--they can both work for different types!

Take a look:

```
Prelude> :t 1
1 :: Num a => a
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

So both `1` *and* `+` are meaningful for *any* type in the `Num` class. So when you write `1 + Bool`, the `1` *could* actually be a `Bool`, if `Bool` had a `Num` instance. In fact, you can do that yourself:

```
instance Num Bool where
  fromInteger x = x /= 0
  (+) = (&&)
  ...
```

Once you do this, `1 + True` will actually work. You will also be able to use numeric literals as bools:

```
*Main> 1 :: Bool
True
*Main> 1 + True
True
```

This also explains why you get the same error regardless of the order of arguments: the only actual problem in your code is the `True`--if that worked, everything else would too.

Comment: @Rumca as you can see from this answer, you have already made sure that both arguments have to be `Bool`. What confuses you is that when you type the value `1` in a Haskell source file, GHC implicitly puts it in a `fromInteger` call, which means that `1` is not necessarily an integer, but rather can be translated to almost any type when you program is compiled. You can test this for yourself – ask ghci what the type for `\n -> n + True` is. It'll say `n` has to be a `Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the contract of Num that any numeric integer literal can be converted to the desired type.

With your declaration, Haskell tries in reality:

```
fromIntegral 1 + True
```

which probably calls your boolean (+) with the first argument undefined. But it doesn't matter, since you never evaluate it.

Try writing it thus:

```
(+) a b = if a then True else False
```

and you'll probably see an error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that the `data Bool` is not an instance of the `class Num`, if you run in `ghci` the following command

```
Prelude> :info Num
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
    -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Num Int -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
```

You can see that a `Num` is a thing that can be added `(+)`, multiplied `(*)`, substracted `(-)`, and so on.

As a `Bool` can't behave like this, it doesn't have an instance of `Num`. That explains the line in the error `No instance for (Num Bool)` since `(+)` can only be used on instances of `Num`

What you are doing in `instance Num Bool where (+) a b = True` is saying that now a `Bool` behaves also like a `Num`, so you have to specify how a `Bool` can be added `(+)`, multiplied `(*)`, etc.

I hope I explained in a simple enough way.

Comment: `Bool` can definitely "behave like this" (`instance Num Bool where { (+)=(||);(*)=(&&);negate=not;abs=id;signum=id;fromInteger=(/=0) }`), it's just that defining a `Num` instance isn't very wise, because it allows for a few more programmer errors to become unnoticed by the type system.

Comment: @Rhymoid: Side note—`(+)` would be better defined as exclusive OR so you get a Boolean ring.